# Why am I getting an error saying that test data has lesser number of features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, libsvm

I am trying to implement the `LinearSVC` model on a data-set containing 25000 movie reviews. 12,500 are positive labelled reviews and the rest are negative. I am trying to vectorize the data using `TfidfVectorizer`.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

k=0

# reading training data from data-set and taking test data as input

rev=input('Enter:')
rev=rev.replace("<br />", " ")
data_folder= "C:/Users/Files/Desktop/Dataset/train"
for sentiment in (["/neg/","/pos/"]):
    #path would be the directory path 
    path=data_folder+sentiment
    #filename will store the NAME of the files that you want to access
    for filename in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
        #open file
        with open(path+ filename,"r",encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
                review=f.read()
                review=review.replace("<br />", " ")
                total.append(review)

# removing stop-words from data

for i in total:
    for j in stop_words:
        if j in i:
            i.replace(j,'')

for i in [rev]:
    for j in stop_words:
        if j in i:
            i.replace(j,'')

c=TfidfVectorizer()
f=c.fit_transform(total).toarray()
tst=c.fit_transform([rev]).toarray()


# 0 for negative data and 1 for positive data

while k!=12500:
    l.append(0)
    k+=1
while k!=25000:
    l.append(1)
    k+=1
m=LinearSVC(random_state=0,tol=1e-5)
m.fit(f,l)

if(m.predict(tst).tolist().count(1)>m.predict(tst).tolist().count(0)):
    print('Positive')
else:
    print('Negative')
```

Every time I run this code, I keep getting this error

```
ValueError: X has 139 features per sample; expecting 79897
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, just had to use `transform()` in place of `fit_transform()` to vectorize the train data i.e.,

```
c=TfidfVectorizer()
f=c.fit_transform(total).toarray()
tst=c.transform([rev]).toarray()
```